# Add spacing using Tailwind class on a map JSX function

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to add space between comments in a react component but any stying I try to apply like adding space-y to it will only start affecting the second comment and so on but the first one will ignore any changes applied

```
<div className="mr-40 ml-40">
  {comments.length > 0 && (
    <div className="bg-slate-600 shadow-lg rounded-lg m-10">
      {comments.map((comment, index) => (
        <div
          key={comment.createdAt}
          className={`border-b border-gray-100 py-4 ${index !== 0 ? 'space-y-4' : ''}`}
        >
          <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
            <h3 className="text-black ml-2">{toUpper(comment.name)}</h3>
            <h4 className="text-gray-500 ml-10">{formatDate(comment.createdAt)}</h4>
          </div>
          <p className="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">{comment.comment}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )}
</div>
```

So I already tried to add space-y over the map function

```
<div className="space-y-4">
  {comments.map((comment) => (
    …
```

but that would only affect the comments from the second one then I tried conditional rendering on  `className={`border-b border-gray-100 py-4 ${index !== 0 ? 'space-y-4' : ''}`}` to see if it would affect all the comments equally but still seems that the first one will not receive any styling change as far as spacing. How could I modify my code so I can add spacing in between each comment equally?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` on all items, consider using a `mt-*` or a `mb-*` class respectively on each comment element like:

```
{comments.map((comment, index) => (
  <div key={comment.createdAt} className="… mt-4">
```